# getting 401 when testing web api response time please assist

Tags: java, http, http-status-code-401

was hoping someone would assist me. 
i have the below code, trying to test web api via http request on java but receiving a 401 unauthorised response. is there a way i can provide a password and confirm my authenticity to the system to get the response code and continue calculations of response time without receiving 401 response?

please see code below

```
public class readCSV {
    public static void main (String [] args) throws IOException
    {
        String fileNames = "data.csv";
        File file = new File(fileNames);// TODO read about file

    try 
        { 
            Scanner inputStream = new Scanner (file);
            inputStream.nextLine();
            int count = 0;
            long responseTime =0;
            if (count > 0 ){ } 
            do
            {
                String data = inputStream.nextLine();// gets the entire string of data
                String [] values = data.split(",");

                System.out.print("Getting value: ");
                count = count + 1;
                System.out.print( count + " ");
                System.out.print(values[1] + values[2] + values[3] + values[4] + values[5] + " ");


                    // open your connection
                        long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
                             URL url = new URL(values[0]);
                             HttpURLConnection http = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
                             int statusCode = http.getResponseCode();
                    //         System.out.print("Status: " + statusCode);
                        HTTPSTATUSPICKER pickStat = new HTTPSTATUSPICKER();
                        pickStat.statusCode(statusCode);

                    // send request, wait for response (the simple socket calls are all blocking)
                        long end = System.currentTimeMillis();
                        responseTime = end-start;
                        System.out.println(" ResponseTime = " + responseTime + " millis");  

            }
            while(inputStream.hasNextLine());
        } 

    catch (FileNotFoundException ex) 
    {
        Logger.getLogger(readCSV.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
        {  
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are getting `401 unauthorised` , then its a clear case of Authorisation problem.
Check you **token** or any auth param you are passing  while making REST call.
Also check your Controller/Rest service layer for auth management in REST(like basic auth, Oauth,or any other).

Comment: on this code, i am currently not passing any credentials... is there a way i can learn how to?

Comment: check REST service producer, what kind of auth is being used, pass the auth param accordingly. refer https://javapapers.com/web-service/restful-services-http-basic-authentication/ and https://howtodoinjava.com/jersey/jersey-rest-security/